# local storage items after refresh page

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction();">Fav Number</button>
<div id="result"></div>
  <!--This code works on chrome-->

<script>
function myFunction() {
// Check browser support
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Store
 var a = prompt("fav number");
    localStorage.setItem("lastname", a);
    // Retrieve
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
} else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
}
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

hello,

is it possible to get local storage items back when you refresh the page?
and if so, how?

Thanks

Dylan,

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: I always use sessionStorage.. I would recommend using this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting and setting `localStorage`data. In following example the data to set is a `Object` (which is handled by `JSON.stringify`). If need to persist a `string` / `int`there is no need in using `JSON.stringify`.

```
var dataObject = { 'item1': 1, 'item2': 2, 'item3': 3 };

// Set localStorage item
localStorage.setItem('dataObject', JSON.stringify(dataObject));

// Retrieve the object from localStorage
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('dataObject');

// console.log retrieved item
console.log('retrieved data Object: ', JSON.parse(retrievedObject));
```

By getting localStorage data when needed, there no need to handle the page refresh part. The `localStorage` data is fetched when needed by application functions and logics.