# How to save data after refreshing a page

Tags: javascript, dom

Here is my script of to do list. I wanna add a new note to my ul list.
li > p > i, i, input :

```
var list = document.querySelector('.list');

document.querySelector('.add-btn').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();  
var input = document.querySelector('.add-input');
  if(input.value !== '') {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
        firstP = document.createElement('p');
        secondP = document.createElement('p');
        firstIc = document.createElement('i');
        secondIc = document.createElement('i');
        input1 = document.createElement('input');

        firstIc.className = 'fas fa-edit';
        secondIc.className = 'fas fa-trash-alt';
        input1.className = 'edit-note';
        input1.setAttribute('type', 'text');

        firstP.textContent = input.value;
        secondP.appendChild(firstIc);
        secondP.appendChild(secondIc);
        li.appendChild(firstP);
        li.appendChild(secondP);
        li.appendChild(input1);
        li.appendChild(li);
  }
});
```

Here is HTML:

```
<div class='container'>
        <h1>Note manager</h1>

        <ul class="list">
            <li>
                <p>First note</p>
                <p><i class="fas fa-edit"></i><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></p>
                <input type="text" name="" class="edit-note">
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>Second note</p>
                <p><i class="fas fa-edit"></i><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></p>
                <input type="text" name="" class="edit-note">
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="add-notes">
          <input type="text" name="" class="add-input" placeholder="Add a note..">
          <button type="submit" class="add-btn"> Add</button>
        </div> 
    </div>
```

And I wanna save added notes when I refresh the page. How can I do this ?
Should I use AJAX >?

Comment: Yeah, I don't know what you are trying to achieve here. You mean add it after runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Look at this line:

```
li.appendChild(li);
```

Here you add element as child of itself (of course it's not possible), looks like you want to do

```
list.appendChild(li);
```

instead.

**EDIT:**

Answer to your updated question: you should post your items to server and save them there or you can use `localStorage` to keep items in browser ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42086616/local-storage-items-after-refresh-page))