# Save and retrieve sidebar open state from local storage

Tags: angular

I am trying to save the open state of my sidebar to the local storage and retrieve that state when the user refreshes the browser. Can anyone assist in achieving this? Here is my code so far.

**sidebar.component**

```
<aside class="frame-sidebar" [ngClass]="open ? 'opened' : 'closed'">  
 <!-- content here -->
</aside>
```

**sidebar.component.ts**

```
constructor(private dataShare: DataShareService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.dataShare.mainSidebarStatus$.subscribe(
      value => this.open = value
    );
  }
  
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

**header.component.ts**

```
constructor(private dataShare: DataShareService) { }

  toggleSidebar() {
    this.dataShare.toggleMainSidebar();
  }
```

**datashare.service**

```
private mainSidebarSource = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true)
  mainSidebarStatus$ = this.mainSidebarSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }
  
  toggleMainSidebar() {
    const mainSidebarStatus = this.mainSidebarSource.value;
    this.mainSidebarSource.next(!mainSidebarStatus)
  }
```

Thank you!

Comment: You could just subscribe to the `mainSidebarStatus$` inside the service itself and save to localstorage whenever the value changes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [local storage items after refresh page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42086616/local-storage-items-after-refresh-page)